# react-native event like componentDidEnter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is there any event like `componentDidEnter`?
Only event `componentDidMount` works, but I need to call function also when page changed using `this.props.navigator.pop();`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidEnter` doesn't work, but `componentWillUpdate`, `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillReceiveProps` works fine. I used `componentWillReceiveProps` in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Combining `componentWillUnmount`, `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` should help you to achieve what you are trying to do. (see [Component Specs and Lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html))